# How can I get a stack overflow error in Python?

Tags: python, stack-overflow

I currently use this code:

```py
def f():
    try:
        f()
    except RecursionError:
        f()

try:
    f()
except RecursionError:
    f()
```

This results in a fatal stack overflow instantly. However, I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this which is much more Pythonic.

Comment: This seems pretty pythonic to me

Comment: You might remove the outer try block, just leave the one in the function.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what prompted this question?

Comment: I don't think crashing the Python interpreter is a very Pythonic thing to do in the first place.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this is CPython-specific. If you try it in PyPy, you'll probably eventually get a `MemoryError` (but only after waiting for your system to go through swap hell for a while, at least in 64-bit), and in Jython you should get a (catchable) Java StackOverflowError rather than a fatal crash.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks, i see that the outer block wasn't needed after all. And, one day when I was checking out the RecursionError I found described on a site, I tried to catch the error and
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Comment: Remove the outer _try_ block and you have a pretty pythonic piece of code. Not sure why you would want to crash Python though

Comment: is the question on how to get the error or how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**8)

def ackermann(m,n):
     if m == 0:
          return (n + 1)
     elif n == 0:
          return ackermann(m - 1, 1)
     else:
          return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1)) 
          
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        print(ackermann(x, y))
```

Python's default recursion limit is 10**4. Changable with setrecursionlimit() so you can get a 'Stack overflow' error because Ackermann function's output is too long.

Comment: Seems over complicated

Answer (score 0):

I like to use

```
def test(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return test(n-1)*n
```

to test max recursion. It will throw a 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' if n is to large.